# Remove specific cell at certain position in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app where when the user submits a picture for a certain "challenge", it removes that challenge from a collectionView that holds a list on many challenges. Currently, in order to identify which challenge was completed, I manually assigned an ID to every one of the 7 cells which directly correspond to their index (first cell has ID of 0 and index of 0). With that information, once I come back to the view with the collectionView, it removes the object at that index by deleting that item from the data array and reloading the collectionView. The problem is that once I remove a cell, the index becomes different than the original index/ID, meaning it removes the wrong cell thereafter.

How can I figure out which cell to actually remove by finding the unique id of that cell which is implemented in the CustomCell class.

In the code, WeeklyViewController is the VC that holds the collection view of challenges.

```
import UIKit

struct CustomData {
    var img: UIImage
    var points: String
    var mainLabel: String
    var timeText: String
    var score: String
    var region: String
    var lineStaticImage: UIImage
    var subtitle: String
    var challengeID: Int
}

class WeeklyViewController: UIViewController {
    var n = Int()
    var selImage = UIImage()
    var recievedCompleteChallengeID = Int()
    var recivedCompleteChallengeBool = Bool()

    @IBOutlet weak var descLabel: UILabel!
    
    var data = [CustomData]()
    
    func completer() {
        
        var masterchallengeList = ["Turn the lights of when you leave the room", "Turn the A/C off when you leave the house/room", "Compost your food from a couple of meals", "Don't let the run the water when brushing", "Walk, Bike, or Run to work, school, or your house", "Tell a friend to practice composting", "Take a walk around your neighborhood"]
        
        var masterSubtitles = ["This week, whenever you leave the room, remember to take a look at the lights and determine whether they can be turned off...and then do it!", "When you leave your house or a section of your household, make it a point to turn off the fan/air-conditioning if it doesn't need to stay running", "Try looking up fun and interesting composting techniques and practice them with a few meal scraps", "Make sure to only use the water when you actually need it while brushing, and not when you are blankly staring into the mirror", "Try to avoid using your car or any mode of transport that uses gasoline; rather, hop on your bike, skateboard, or your own feet", "Once you figured out how you want to compost meal scraps, share it with a friend and ask them to send you a picture", "Many times, we forget that there can be an adventure other than our phones and computers, so open the door and go around your neighborhood" ]
         
        data = [
            CustomData(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "green"), points: "5", mainLabel: masterchallengeList[0], timeText: "⏰ Ends at midnight", score: "+\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50))", region: "Community", lineStaticImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueline"), subtitle: masterSubtitles[0], challengeID: 0),
            CustomData(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "green"), points: "5", mainLabel: masterchallengeList[1], timeText: "⏰ Ends at midnight", score: "+\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50))", region: "Carbon Footprint", lineStaticImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueline"), subtitle: masterSubtitles[1], challengeID: 1),
            CustomData(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "green"), points: "5", mainLabel: masterchallengeList[2], timeText: "⏰ Ends at midnight", score: "+\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50))", region: "Community", lineStaticImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueline"), subtitle: masterSubtitles[2],challengeID: 2),
            CustomData(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "green"), points: "5", mainLabel: masterchallengeList[3], timeText: "⏰ Ends at midnight", score: "+\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50))", region: "Carbon Footprint", lineStaticImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueline"), subtitle: masterSubtitles[3],challengeID: 3),
            CustomData(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "green"), points: "5", mainLabel: masterchallengeList[4], timeText: "⏰ Ends at midnight", score: "+\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50))", region: "Community", lineStaticImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueline"), subtitle: masterSubtitles[4],challengeID: 4),
            CustomData(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "green"), points: "5", mainLabel: masterchallengeList[5], timeText: "⏰ Ends at midnight", score: "+\(Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50))", region: "Carbon Footprint", lineStaticImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "blueline"), subtitle: masterSubtitles[5],challengeID: 5)
         ]
    }

    fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout =  UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        completer()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
        
        collectionView.contentInset.left = 20
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        print(recivedCompleteChallengeBool)
        print(recievedCompleteChallengeID)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        challengeRemover()
    }
    
    func challengeRemover() {
        if recivedCompleteChallengeBool {
            data.remove(at: recievedCompleteChallengeID)
            collectionView.reloadData()
            print("removed at \(recievedCompleteChallengeID)")
        }
    }
}

extension WeeklyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 250, height: 400)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 92, green: 219, blue: 149, alpha: 1)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        return cell
    }
   
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        n = indexPath.row
        print("selected obj at \(n)")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "challengeSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var detailController = segue.destination as! SecondChallengeViewController
        detailController.dataValues = "\(data[n])"
        detailController.regionR = data[n].region
        detailController.titleLabelLabel =  data[n].mainLabel
        detailController.points = data[n].score
        detailController.subLabel  = data[n].subtitle
        detailController.receiverChallengeID = data[n].challengeID
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
}


class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var id = Int()
    var data: CustomData? {
        didSet{
            guard  let data = data else { return }
            bg.image = data.img
            aa.text = data.mainLabel
            timetext.text = data.timeText
            scoreText.text = data.score
            region.text = data.region
            lineView.image = data.lineStaticImage
            id = data.challengeID
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "carousel3")
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        return iv 
    }()
    
    fileprivate let aa: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel()
        iv.text = "furf"
        iv.numberOfLines = 0
        iv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: .bold)
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 100)
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.isEnabled = true
        iv.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 3/255, green: 29/255, blue: 59/255, alpha: 1)
        iv.textAlignment = .natural
        iv.sizeToFit()
        iv.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return iv
    }()
    
    fileprivate let timetext: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel()
        iv.text = "timeText"
        iv.numberOfLines = 0
        iv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 30)
        iv.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 3/255, green: 29/255, blue: 59/255, alpha: 1)
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.textAlignment = .natural
        iv.sizeToFit()
        iv.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return iv
    }()
    
    fileprivate let scoreText: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel()
        iv.text = "scoreText"
        iv.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 3/255, green: 29/255, blue: 59/255, alpha: 1)
        iv.numberOfLines = 0
        iv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 50)
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.textAlignment = .natural
        iv.sizeToFit()
        iv.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return iv
    }()
    
    fileprivate let region: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel()
        iv.text = "regionText"
        iv.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 3/255, green: 29/255, blue: 59/255, alpha: 1)
        iv.numberOfLines = 0
        iv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .light)
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 50)
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.textAlignment = .natural
        iv.sizeToFit()
        iv.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return iv
    }()
    
    fileprivate let lineView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 20)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.sizeToFit()
        return iv
    }()
    
    fileprivate let line2View: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 20)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.sizeToFit()
        return iv
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(bg)
        self.contentView.addSubview(aa)
        self.contentView.addSubview(timetext)
        self.contentView.addSubview(scoreText)
        self.contentView.addSubview(region)
        self.contentView.addSubview(lineView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(line2View)
        
        bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        aa.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        aa.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        aa.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -260).isActive = true
        aa.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        
        timetext.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aa.bottomAnchor, constant: 230).isActive = true
        timetext.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        timetext.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        timetext.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        
        scoreText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: aa.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        scoreText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        scoreText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        
        region.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
        region.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        region.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        
        lineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreText.bottomAnchor, constant: 140).isActive = true
        lineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        lineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        line2View.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scoreText.bottomAnchor, constant: 137).isActive = true
        line2View.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        line2View.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The VC that has the detailed view of each challenge where you can select and submit a picture is here:

```swift
class SecondChallengeViewController: UIViewController{
     
    var dataValues = String()
    var points = String()
    var titleLabelLabel = String()
    var regionR = String()
    var subLabel = String()
    var receiverChallengeID = Int()
    var challengeComp = Bool()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var submittedPicture: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var challengeTitle: UILabel!
    var selImage = UIImage()
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var regionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointstogiveLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        assignValues()
        print(dataValues)
        print(points)
   
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
              navigationItem.title = "Dashboard"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] 
    }
    
    func assignValues() {
        regionLabel.text = regionR
        challengeTitle.text = titleLabelLabel
        pointstogiveLabel.text = "\(points) evoPoints"
        subtitleLabel.text = subLabel
    }
    
    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        presentPhotoActionSheet()
    }
    
    func setSubmittedPicture() {
        submittedPicture.image = selImage
        submittedPicture.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        submitButton.alpha = 1
    }
    
    func showToast(controller: UIViewController, message : String, seconds: Double) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        alert.view.alpha = 0.6
        alert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        controller.present(alert, animated: true)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + seconds) {
            alert.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if(submittedPicture != nil){
            challengeCompleted()
        }
    }
    
    func challengeCompleted() {
        showToast(controller: self, message: "You Successfully Completed a Challenge", seconds: 2)
        submitButton.alpha = 0
        submittedPicture.alpha = 0
        challengeComp = true
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var challengePanelVC = segue.destination as! WeeklyViewController
        if(challengeComp){
            challengePanelVC.recievedCompleteChallengeID = receiverChallengeID
            challengePanelVC.recivedCompleteChallengeBool = challengeComp
        }
    }
}

extension SecondChallengeViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
   
    func presentPhotoActionSheet() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Challenge Picture", message: "How would share your challenge with us", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.presentCamera()
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.presentPhotoPicker()
        }))
        
        present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }

    func presentCamera() {
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .camera
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.allowsEditing = true
        present(vc, animated: true)
        
    }

    func presentPhotoPicker(){
        
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.allowsEditing = true
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        guard let selectedImage =  info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else{
            return}
         selImage = selectedImage
         setSubmittedPicture()
        }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                                   animated flag: Bool,
                                   completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

How can I figure out which card specifically I have to remove?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a userDefaults dictionary with a user default counter. The counter would increase for each new element. The counter would be your key in the dictionary and would be your cell identifier. You would then load the dictionary data into your cells and remove the dictionary key and value for each cell you remove. When you reload your data the cell will be only the ones defined by your dictionary.

This link explains the dictionary part. [Explanation](https://cocoacasts.com/ud-4-how-to-store-a-dictionary-in-user-defaults-in-swift)